# Logic App not parsing body from ADF anymore

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I'm triggering Logic Apps (around 30) from the Data Factory V2. I am passing a body to the HTTP trigger, which is in JSON in Data Factory V2. The body is different for almost all Logic Apps.

Last week there was an issue that the 'When HTTP Request is received' step is not processing the body from the Data Factory in a correct matter.

Please note that both the Logic Apps and Data Factory haven't changed in months and were working without any problems up to last week.

This happened last week also, but this resolved 'itself', suggesting it was an issue at Logic App side. Currently all Logic Apps keep failing. I've tried rerunning the Logic Apps many times. @AzureSupport redirected me to our CSP, but they are not really helping at the moment.

Body in the ADF pipeline (sanitized the url):

```
"typeProperties": {
    "url": "https://prod-50.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443 /<....>",
    "method": "POST",
    "body": {
        "customer": "@pipeline().parameters.customer",
        "token": "@pipeline().parameters.token",
        "tennant": "@pipeline().parameters.tennant",
        "baseuri": "@pipeline().parameters.baseuri",
        "connectorTrans": "@pipeline().parameters.connectorTrans",
        "connectorNonTrans": "@pipeline().parameters.connectorNonTrans",
        "datum": "@formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-1),'s')"
    }
}
```

The last succesful run parsed the body from the Data Factory as follows (sanitized ofcourse):

```
"body": {
    "customer": "<customerName>",
    "token": "<token>",
    "tennant": null,
    "baseuri": "<baseUri>",
    "connectorTrans": "<connectorName>",
    "connectorNonTrans": "<connectorName2>",
    "datum": "<date>"
}
```

The runs that are failing are all showing the same problem, the body is not being parsed correctly:

```
"body": "{\r\n  \"customer\": \"<customerName>\",\r\n  \"token\": \"<token>\",\r\n  \"tennant\": null,\r\n  \"baseuri\": \"<baseUri>\",\r\n  \"connectorTrans\": \"<connectorName>\",\r\n  \"connectorNonTrans\": \"<connectorName2>\",\r\n  \"datum\": \"<date>\"\r\n}"
```

It is all in one single line, including \r\n and escape characters.

This is resulting in the Logic App not being able to use the values in the fields passed on by the Data Factory.

All help or pointers are much appreciated.

Running the Logic App from Postman, with the exact same body as from the Data Factory is working without any problems.

Comment: You seem to have a server side problem. You should ask the service provider for help. There's not much Stack Overflow can do because there's no code available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue, you need to add header content type application/json in your web component in ADF which calling logic app.

[image: Check this]

Comment: We figured this out exactly this morning. Strange that this wasn't a problem before.